# using set_intersection with set giving an error?

Tags: c++, c++11

getting error in the following code.. in  line no 38 i am getting error why i dont know but i tried in many ways but it didnot solved plz solve the my problem using set_intersection with set giving an error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
#define now 5519    
int main()
{   
    set<int> a[now];
    set<float>dist[now];
    set<int>insect;
    //set<int> v(10);
    FILE *fwp=fopen("wp02","r");
    int w,at,dis;
    set<int>::iterator it;
    while(1)
    {
        if(fscanf(fwp,"%d",&w)==EOF)
        {
            fclose(fwp);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            fscanf(fwp,"%d%f\n",&at,&dis);
            a[w].insert(at);
            dist[w].insert(dis);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<now;i++)
    {
        if(a[i].size()==0)
            continue;
        for(int j=i;j<now;j++)
        {
            if(a[j].size()==0)
                continue;
            set<int> v;
            //it=set_intersection (a[i], a[j], v);   
            it=set_intersection (a[i],a[i]+a[i].size(), a[j], a[j]+a[j].size(), v);
            //it=set_intersection (a[i].begin(),a[i].end(), a[j].begin(), a[j].end(), v.begin());
        //  v.resize(it-v.begin());
            for (it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
            {
                cout << ' ' << *it;
            }

        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you need help with solving an error, it's a good idea to *post* the error.

Comment: What is supposed to be in the file `wp02`?

Comment: What are you talking about? What error? Is it compilation error? Is it run-time assertion failure? Is is a segfault? We are not telepathic here.

Comment: set_intersection (a[i],a[i]+a[i].size(), a[j], a[j]+a[j].size(), v);

Please explain in English what you are trying to accomplish here. The syntax is way wrong to deduce it from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal compilable example of set_intersection (in flavor of your code):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> x[10];
    int i = 2;
    int j = 3;

    std::set<int> v;
    std::set_intersection(x[i].begin(), x[i].end(), x[j].begin(), x[j].end(), std::inserter(v, v.begin()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at some documentation for `set_intersection` e.g. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) or [SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_intersection.html)

You'll see it doesn't take a `std::set` or any other container as an argument

Answer (score 0):

`std::set_intersection` has nothing at all to do with `std::set`. The algorithm operates on two ranges and copies each element that is present in both into the output stream. Each of the input ranges is specified by a pair of iterators; the first iterator points to the first element in the range and the second iterator points past the end of the range. That's the standard convention for ranges. You can get pairs of iterators from any standard container, as well as many other places. For standard containers, the member functions `begin()` and `end()` return iterators that designate the range of elements held by the container. So for any container type:

```
my_container container;
// stuff objects into container
my_container other_container;
// stuff objects into other_container
my_container intersection;
std::set_intersection(container.begin(), container.end(),
    other_container.begin(), other_container.end(),
    std::back_inserter(intersection));
```